# Is there any way to remove the caption blurbs beneath each of the application name headings in the whisker menu in XFCE?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, window-manager, xfce

I feel it is unnecessary and too much text becomes distracting and disorientating for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open the settings dialog (right-click on the panel button and choose "Properties") and uncheck the option labelled "Show application descriptions".